# SFTP package for automation

Tags: sftp

I have various SFTP automation projects that I am looking to move to Linux. I could easily script this in via Python, bash or something similar.

But is there a package or something of the sort intended for SFTP automation that could keep things more consistent and be in one central location? Having 10 different scripts with all different code feels like it's less future proof than it should be.

What generally occurs:

- Once a day SFTP batch
- Specific file types (not all files) uploaded
- Only uploads files created in last 24 hours
- Has to traverse within 1 subfolder level

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `scp` and `rsync` if you haven't come across these before. They work over a ssh connection, `rsync` is particularly good at optimising redundant copies if files haven't been modified.

`rsnapshot` is a perl script that uses `rsync`, to maintain several sets (hourly,daily,weekly,monthly) backups might be useful.

Depends really how you are using `sftp`.

Comment: I use `scp` fairly often. I added details into my post, but I'll research it if it can do my automation scenarios.